# Android : convert an audio file into array of complex numbers (for FFT)

Tags: android, file, audio, byte, fft

In order to process a FFT on an audio signal, I first need to **convert my audio file into an array of complex numbers**. I still don't understand if this part requires to save a .CSV of .TXT file on my sd card or if I can simply stock data in my application as a variable.
I would simply like to understand how this part really works in order to go further in my FFT program : **from my .3gpp audio file** (by the way, is it a good format to use for what I am doing?) saved on my sd card, what should I do to have my array of complex numbers, the input for the FFT ?

If anyone has an example of existing code used to convert audio file to binary data, I would really appreciate to take a look at it and to understand how to implement it in my activity.

Comment: If you're goign to use a complex-to-complex FFT then just set the imaginary parts of the input to zero and the real parts equal to your audio sample values.

Comment: First, the OP will need to convert the file into an array of uncompressed PCM samples.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I made a new audio recorder using the "AudioRecord" class instead of Media Recorder. I know get a .wav file, which is an uncompressed 16Bit PCM. 
I guess it's more suitable for using as an input for a FFT. But I still don't have any idea of what is the next step to process a FFT and get a spectogram out of this. Not that easy for beginner to learn about this with concrete examples!

Comment: The "Related" section in the right side-panel lists a large collection of related FFT questions, many also mentioning Android. That's a good place to start.